# Reversing the display of items News Feed

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image]

I want to reserve every inside of element box1 right to left every hour
and every 24 hour / a day, element box1, box2 and box 3 will going to up from bottom..

```css
.box {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
.box :nth-child(1) { order: 4; }
.box :nth-child(2) { order: 1; }
.box :nth-child(3) { order: 2; }
.box :nth-child(4) { order: 3; }
```

```html
<div class="box" id="box1">
  <div><a href="#">One</a></div>
  <div><a href="#">Two</a></div>
  <div><a href="#">Three</a></div>
  <div><a href="#">Four</a></div>
</div>
<div class="box" id="box2">
  <div><a href="#">One</a></div>
  <div><a href="#">Two</a></div>
  <div><a href="#">Three</a></div>
  <div><a href="#">Four</a></div>
</div>
<div class="box" id="box3">
  <div><a href="#">One</a></div>
  <div><a href="#">Two</a></div>
  <div><a href="#">Three</a></div>
  <div><a href="#">Four</a></div>
</div>
<div class="box" id="box4">
  <div><a href="#">One</a></div>
  <div><a href="#">Two</a></div>
  <div><a href="#">Three</a></div>
  <div><a href="#">Four</a></div>
</div>
```

above is my code .. 
just can reserve inside box "right to left"
but bottom to top isn't yet ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reorder the whole rows exactly the same way you reordered the items of one row. Apply `display: flex;` on the container element, but this time set `flex-direction: column;`. Now you can reorder the rows with the `order` attribute:

```css
.box {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
.box :nth-child(1) { order: 4; }
.box :nth-child(2) { order: 1; }
.box :nth-child(3) { order: 2; }
.box :nth-child(4) { order: 3; }

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.container :nth-child(1) { order: 4; }
.container :nth-child(2) { order: 1; }
.container :nth-child(3) { order: 2; }
.container :nth-child(4) { order: 3; }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box" id="box1">
    <div><a href="#">1 One</a></div>
    <div><a href="#">1 Two</a></div>
    <div><a href="#">1 Three</a></div>
    <div><a href="#">1 Four</a></div>
  </div>
  <div class="box" id="box2">
    <div><a href="#">2 One</a></div>
    <div><a href="#">2 Two</a></div>
    <div><a href="#">2 Three</a></div>
    <div><a href="#">2 Four</a></div>
  </div>
  <div class="box" id="box3">
    <div><a href="#">3 One</a></div>
    <div><a href="#">3 Two</a></div>
    <div><a href="#">3 Three</a></div>
    <div><a href="#">3 Four</a></div>
  </div>
  <div class="box" id="box4">
    <div><a href="#">4 One</a></div>
    <div><a href="#">4 Two</a></div>
    <div><a href="#">4 Three</a></div>
    <div><a href="#">4 Four</a></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: and how to reserve every time ? see picture above ? left to right every one hour and bottom to top every 24 hour .. ?

Comment: @TaufiqHidayah I'm not the author of this answer, but to answer your comment here: you need to develop that part.  You didn't include any javascript in your question, but considering that's a separate issue, I would encourage you to try and work it out yourself and then post a another question here on SO if you get stuck.  To get you started, you can get an offset class based on the current hour using the following javascript: `['offset-one', 'offset-two', 'offset-three', 'offset-four'][new Date().getHours() % 4]`

Comment: @JosephMarikle oke thx ... maybe you can give me keyword to implement this problem in javascript ?  :D

Comment: @TaufiqHidayah You're requirements are pretty convenient with it being a 4x4 grid.  Maybe something like this will get you started? https://jsfiddle.net/5kbfvoeo/1. Edit: had a bug with the CSS.  corrected.